# If Element ID exists then Hide Other Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ecommerce website that has multiple prices for a given item. I am trying to set up a bit of script that will hide a price, if the lower price class is present on the page.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font>
                    <div class="product_listprice">199.99</div>
                </font>
                <font>
                    <div class="product_productprice">179.99</div>
                </font>
                <b>
                    <div class="product_saleprice">159.99</div>
                </b>
                <font>
                    <div class="product_discountprice">139.99</div>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Essentially what I need is a script that will hide .product_productprice if .product_saleprice exists on the page, and will hide both .product_saleprice and .product_productprice if .product_discountprice exists.

Here's what I've come up with so far with some google digging.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ( $(".product_discountprice").size() )
        $(".product_saleprice, .product_productprice").hide();
        });
    });   
</script>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? I'm a jquery novice, so I'm sure there is a better way to do this out there...

Comment: `<font>`? The 1990s called and wants its html back.

Comment: Tell me about it, please send your concerns and comments to www.volusion.com

Comment: @MarcB You do realise that the current finalised version of HTML (4) was initially released in the 1990s :)

Comment: `.size()` should be `.length`

Comment: @tymeJV that is not the issue here, size() works fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Essentially what I need is a script that will hide .product_productprice
// if .product_saleprice exists on the page...
if ($('.product_saleprice').length) {
    $('.product_productprice').hide();
}

// ...and will hide both .product_saleprice and .product_productprice
// if .product_discountprice exists.
if ($('.product_discountprice').length ) {
    $('.product_saleprice, .product_productprice').hide();
}
```

---

Update that adds a new class name, instead of hiding:

```
if ($('.product_saleprice').length) {
    $('.product_productprice').addClass('some-class');
}

if ($('.product_discountprice').length ) {
    $('.product_saleprice, .product_productprice').addClass('some-class');
}
```

Comment: `.size()` is the same as `.length`.

Comment: Except that [`.size()` is deprecated in favor of `.length`](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

Comment: Yea, that fixed the bit I had already come up with. However this will only hide if the discountprice is present. How can I "double this up to hide if discountprice is not present?

Comment: Essentially I need it to also conditionally hide if just saleprice and productprice are there.

Comment: So what that it's deprecated? It's still there, still works the same as `.length`. Hence can't be the issue.

Comment: @dfsq I never said that `.size()` was broken, I'm just encouraging use of the non-deprecated approach.  Deprecation usually means removal at some point in the future, at which point it will be broken.

Comment: I know this isn't part of my question, and if you don't answer I'll still accept this answer, but I was wondering if it's possible to change or add a class to the other prices instead of hiding them.

Comment: I know, I'm just implied that you pointed to different issue, instead of explain that OP has problem with curly braces. But length is of course preferred.

Comment: @AlexRitter Absolutely, please see the addition at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @dfsq Ahh, I understand your point. My intention wasn't to imply that the root cause was using `.size()`.  I was simply trying to fix the code, and remove the use of deprecated APIs in the process. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3481uqa4/1/

```
  if ($(".product_discountprice").length) {
        $(".product_productprice, .product_saleprice").hide();       
    } else if ($(".product_saleprice").length) {
        $(".product_productprice").hide();
    }
```

Will hide both product price and sale price if product_discountprice exists, else if sale price exist hide product price. If neither of them exists, show the product price.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.. Not sure if it is correct.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if($(".product_discountprice").length()){
                $('.product_saleprice').hide();
                $('.product_productprice').hide();
            });
        });   
    </script>
```